# Flash - detect large combination of keys

Tags: flash

I want to identify large combination of keys pressed like

Ctrl + Alt + Shift + D

In actionscript to open some Easter Egg, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a model to track key state, then invalidate on key down to test if your combination evaluates true:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    [SWF(percentWidth = 100, percentHeight = 100, backgroundColor = 0xefefef, frameRate = 60)]
    public class X extends Sprite
    {

        private var controlKeyDown:Boolean = false;
        private var altKeyDown:Boolean = false;
        private var shiftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
        private var dKeyDown:Boolean = false;

        public function X()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
        }

        protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch (event.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.ALTERNATE:
                    altKeyDown = true;
                    break;
                case Keyboard.CONTROL:
                    controlKeyDown = true;
                    break;
                case Keyboard.SHIFT:
                    shiftKeyDown = true;
                    break;
                case Keyboard.D:
                    dKeyDown = true;
                    break;
            }

            invalidateKeyDown();
        }

        protected function keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch (event.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.ALTERNATE:
                    altKeyDown = false;
                    break;
                case Keyboard.CONTROL:
                    controlKeyDown = false;
                    break;
                case Keyboard.SHIFT:
                    shiftKeyDown = false;
                    break;
                case Keyboard.D:
                    dKeyDown = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected function invalidateKeyDown():Boolean
        {
            if (altKeyDown && controlKeyDown && shiftKeyDown && dKeyDown)
            {
                trace("easter egg.");
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```